# JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Tunnel" on React Native App when using fetch to send request to backend

Tags: node.js, json, react-native

Hi i am trying to send requests from my react native front end to my nodejs backend API. Whether its a get or post request, this error randomly pops up and has been very annoying. I have tested the API url which i expose using ngrok and it works perfectly fine on postman so I can't understand why when my frontend tries to send a request it does not work. Sometimes it works but sometimes it shows this weird error that i cannot resolve. Greatly appreciate any help!

```
JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Tunnel"
 * [native code]:null in parse
 * node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
 * node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:123:25 in setImmediate$argument_0
 * node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:146:14 in _callTimer
 * node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:194:17 in _callImmediatesPass
 * node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:458:30 in callImmediates
 * [native code]:null in callImmediates
 * node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:407:6 in __callImmediates
 * node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:143:6 in __guard$argument_0
 * node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
 * node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:142:17 in __guard$argument_0
 * [native code]:null in flushedQueue
 * [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
```

This one the the places in my code where im using fetch to send a request and this error surfaces.

```
export const authenticate = (username, password) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/api/users/login`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          username,
          password,
        }),
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        const errorResData = await response.json();
        const errorId = errorResData.message;
        let message = "Something went wrong!";
        if (errorId === "USERNAME_NOT_FOUND") {
          message = "This username could not be found!";
        } else if (errorId === "INVALID_PASSWORD") {
          message = "This password is not valid!";
        }
        throw new Error(message);
      }

      const resData = await response.json();
      console.log(resData)

      dispatch({
        type: AUTHENTICATE,
        user: resData.user,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err) // ERROR HAPPENS HERE
      throw err;
    }
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error, was using dotenv for my env variables and found out it was because my env variables were not updating which caused the tunnel url to not be found. Running the app using: expo r -c will update the env variables and solve the problem.